# IOS 7 / IOS 6 custom toolbar barbuttonitem

Tags: ios6, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am trying to provide support for both iOS7 and iOS6 using storyboards. I have designed a custom barbuttonitem for iOS7 which looks like this:

[image: custom iOS7 barbuttonitem]

It looks just fine.  The problem is how to specify another image for the barbuttonitem for iOS6. Obviously the iOS6 and the iOS 7 images need to be different sizes. The iOS 6 button looks like this:

[image: iOS6 rendering of barbuttonitem]

How do you do this in the storyboard? Is there some sort of suffix or naming convention to allow an iOS7 image to be distinguished from an iOS6 image?

Thanks Jim

Answer (score 0):

For something like that, you'll probably need to programatically change the appearance based on the running version.

I've used something like this:

```
#define IS_IOS_6 ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"6"])
// or
// #define IS_IOS_6 (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)

if (IS_IOS_6) {
    [self.barButtonItem setBackgroundImage:ios6Image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
} else {
    [self.barButtonItem setBackgroundImage:ios7Image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the only way to make this work. I looked at the image asset catalog also, and it does not support different iOS options for bar button items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to load a different image based on iOS version.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

// Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier

} 

else {

// Load resources for iOS 7 or later

}
```